# Why LWP::UserAgent is imported by require LWP::UserAgent instead of use LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, require, perl-module

I'm pretty new to this language but I've been using `use` to import a specific module before,

why `LWP::UserAgent` uses `require` to do the job as from `perldoc LWP::UserAgent`:

```
require LWP::UserAgent;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
```

is the same as

```
BEGIN {
    require LWP::UserAgent;
    import LWP::UserAgent;
}
```

If `require LWP::UserAgent;` is acceptable, that goes to show that `import` does nothing for LWP::UserAgent. Maybe the point of the documentation's use of `require` is to subtly imply this?

The only difference between `require LWP::UserAgent;` and `use LWP::UserAgent;` is thus when `require` is executed. For the former, it happens after the entire file has been compiled. For the latter, it occurs as soon as that statement has been compiled. In practical terms, there's no much difference for object-oriented modules.

Personally, I use

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );
```

That's the same as

```
BEGIN {
    require LWP::UserAgent;
}
```

That way, I'm guaranteed not to import anything I don't want, and I use the familiar `use` I use for other modules.

- [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functinos/require.html)
- [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functinos/use.html)

Comment: so the difference is `import LWP::UserAgent; `,what exactly does this do then?

Comment: `import LWP::UserAgent` is a variant syntax for `LWP::UserAgent->import()`; it calls a class method named `import`.  Normally, that will export functions into the caller's namespace using the [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) module, but it can actually do anything the module author chooses to do.

Answer (score 0):

`require Module::Name` has the same effect as `use`, only at run-time, not compile-time.  This is sometimes advantageous when you want to conditionally require a module.  I don't think there's any particular reason for the doc to say `require` instead of `use`.

Comment: the compile time and run time difference only exists for `fastcgi` where Perl is persistent,not in `CGI` mode,right?

Comment: @Learning, no. `require` will only load and execute the module once, whether `require` is done at compile-time or at run-time.

Comment: Learning: no, in general.  If you have other code before the require, it will execute before the require fails.

Comment: `require` does not have the same effect as `use`. The `use` requires the module, then calls its `import` method.

Comment: @briandfoy yes, use optionally (opt-out) calls an import method and optionally (opt-in) does a version check.  but in the context of an OO module, it didn't feel worth making the distinction

Comment: There's no optional about it. `use` happens at compile time and calls `import`.

Comment: @briandfoy `use Foo ();` does not call import

Comment: Yeah, but you don't explain that doing extra work like giving it an empty import list is the thing that makes your answer make sense, and the OP isn't asking about `use Foo ();`. Replacing a bare `require` with a bare `use` and no extra intervention still calls import. I suggest you simply delete this answer.

Answer (score -3):

For people who come from google search and looking this solutions:

For Message Error: LWP::UserAgent not found at ./apache_accesses line 86.

Solution:
apt-get install libwww-perl

Comment: This question was about `use` vs. `require`, using LWP as an example. It is not about getting LWP to work. Also, your answer is Debian-specific.

Comment: I know but i looked for this soultion and got first this site from google.